# What was this object at the end of an episode of The Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, object-identification

Potential Spoilers Ahead!

At the end of Season 3 Episode 21, Team Flash has successfully

> built the Speed Force <strike>cannon</strike> bazooka.

However, a couple of them mention that it will need a huge power source to work. As the show fades out, Barry looks (wistfully? knowingly?) off to the side and the last view that watchers get is of:

> a reddish, glowing stone in some form of container, next to a menacing King Shark.

What is this, and was Barry's aforementioned look an indication to viewers that he was thinking of it? I can't recall if this is the first appearance on the show or if my memory of previous episodes is failing me. I have not seen the most recent episode of The Flash: SE3E22, *Infantino Street*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red object shown at the end of S03E21 is some sort of technology/power source from a Dominator ship acquired during the crossover event earlier this season.

[Lyla explains](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-flash-2014&episode=s03e22):

> It's a piece of the Dominators' technology. We got it from the ship that crashed in Central City.